# Fabric Beta API Add Testers

Tags: android, google-fabric, fabric-beta

**Fabric Beta** tool is very helpfull for app development. But now I would like to manage users from external app.

This means to be able at least **Add Tester** and **Remove Testers**. Did some work with such **Fabric API**?

I know about distribution plugins, but we would like to split tester administration from new release distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

Fabric doesn't have a public API for doing this on the fly in an external way or in your own app. The most versatile ways to add testers would be our plugin with [fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/crashlytics/) or distributing via [Gradle commands](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html), but you've already noted that you know about the distribution plugins.

Comment: Thanks for response. Do you have any plan to add API in future?